# Can I email the testNG reports directly through selenium?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, testng

I want to send the testNG reports directly through mail to the stakeholders once its complete execution. What is the best possible way for it?

Answer (score 1):

There are at least 2 approaches:

1. If Jenkins is used in your company, you create a job that runs tests and then e-mails report by [Email ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin).
2. Or you can add such functionality to @BeforeSuite method with [JavaMail](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail).